# How to use GCC Profile Guided Optimization with large Makefile?

Tags: c++, gcc, pgo

I'm trying to figure out PGO with GCC, but all the examples I can find online just feature a single `.c` file where the compilation is quite straightforward. Are there any resources that talk about how this is meant to work for larger projects where multiple `.o` files are being compiled and linked together? Like, do I just toss in an `-fprofile-generate` and `-fprofile-use` flags like normal? Since if so, the resulting `.gcda` files get distributed across multiple directories, and I can't tell if `-fprofile-use` is picking up on them. Should I export everything into a single benchmarking folder?

For context, I have tried both these things and have not had any luck speeding up my current code. But I can't tell whether I'm doing something incorrectly, or if my code just isn't really optimizable with PGO.